# jquery validation in textfield

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, jquery-plugins

I got plugin(jquery form validator) when i was surf in google, I want to make form validation, plugin use in form validation, its work perfect but In console show error,

> jquery.form-validator.min.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at HTMLDocument.f (jquery.form-validator.min.js:9)
>       at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
>       at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js:3)
>       at Object.trigger (jquery.js:3)
>       at m.fn.init.triggerHandler (jquery.js:3)
>       at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
>       at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:2)

```js
$.validate({
  form: '#form',
  modules: 'location, date, security, file',
});

// Restrict presentation length
$('#presentation').restrictLength($('#pres-max-length'));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-lg-5">
  {!! Form::label('quantities', 'Traded Quantity:') !!} {!! Form::text('quantities', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'data-validation'=>'length number', 'data-validation-length'=>'3-12', 'data-validation-error-msg'=>'User name has to be an alphanumeric
  value (3-12 chars)'])!!}
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a `#pres-max-length` field in the HTML?

Comment: No not use #pres-max-length, it use data-validation-length -@RoryMcCrossan

Comment: $('#presentation').restrictLength($('#pres-max-length'));
This line put in  comment, its work fine -@RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Exactly my point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate it as the following:

```
    $('#form').validate({
       rules: {
        quantities: {
            required: true,
            rangelength: [3, 12],
        },
        other_input_name: "required",
     },
  });
```